# Array issue in Vulkan Uniform

Tags: glsl, vulkan

Firstly, everything works fine when I pass one lightPos

```
struct UniformBufferObject {
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 model;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 view;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 proj;
    alignas(16) glm::vec3 lightColor;
    alignas(16) glm::vec3 viewPos;
    alignas(16) glm::vec3 lightPos;
};
```

but when I change the lightPos to array

```
struct UniformBufferObject {
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 model;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 view;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 proj;
    alignas(16) glm::vec3 lightColor;
    alignas(16) glm::vec3 viewPos;
    alignas(32) glm::vec3 lightPos[2];
};
```

I think I meet some alignment issue.
I pass the same value to lightPos0 and lightPos1, but the values I get in frag shader are strange

```
glm::vec3 defaultLightPos1 = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
UniformBufferObject ubo{};
ubo.lightPos[0] = defaultLightPos1;
ubo.lightPos[1] = defaultLightPos1;

//frag shader
layout(binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
    vec3 lightColor;
    vec3 viewPos;
    vec3 lightPos[2];
} ubo;

void main() {
    outColor = vec4(ubo.lightPos[0/1], 1.0);
}
```

when the

```
outColor = vec4(ubo.lightPos[0], 1.0);
```

I get

[image]

when the

```
outColor = vec4(ubo.lightPos[1], 1.0);
```

I get

[image]

the result don't change when I change the

```
alignas(32) glm::vec3 lightPos[2]
```

to

```
alignas(16) glm::vec3 lightPos[2]
```

Comment: GLSL UB array elements of type `vec3` are aligned to the size of `vec4`. However the elements of `glm::vec3 lightPos[2];` are aligned to 4 bytes.

Comment: @Rabbid76, thanks for replying. You mean I should change to alignas(4) glm::vec3 lightPos[2]?

Comment: when I use alignas(4) glm::vec3 lightPos[2], lightPos[0] would get green cube, lightPos[1] would get red cube

Comment: No, you should use `glm::vec4` instead of `glm::vec3`

Comment: @Rabbid76, thanks! That works, but would you mind give more details about the reason? uniform vec3 lightPos works fine in OpenGL, https://learnopengl.com/PBR/Lighting   https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/6.pbr/1.1.lighting/1.1.pbr.fs

Comment: If you have an array of `vec3`, each element takes the size of `vec4`

Comment: Get it, thanks so much!